# Вывод элементов массива по порядку при нажатии

Tags: javascript, массивы, циклы

При нажатии на button выводятся все элементы массива:

```
var wrapper = document.getElementById('wrapper');
var button = document.getElementById("button");
var array = ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"];
button.onclick = function() {
    var addString = "";
    for (i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
        addString += array[i] + "<br>";
        };
    wrapper.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", addString);
};
```

Как выполнить поочередный вывод, к примеру, пяти элементов из массива при каждом нажатии кнопки? Таким образом: *1-е нажатие - выводится 0,1,2,3,4, *2-е нажатие - следующие пять и т.д.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно добавить переменные и проверять их в цикле. Вот, например, так:

```js
var wrapper = document.getElementById('wrapper');
var button = document.getElementById('button');
var array = ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"];
var currentIndex = 0;
var currentLimit = 5;

function showArray() {
  currentLimit += currentIndex;
  for (currentIndex; currentIndex < currentLimit && currentIndex < array.length; currentIndex++) {
    wrapper.innerHTML += array[currentIndex] + "<br />";
  };
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="go" onclick="showArray();" />
<div id='wrapper'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var $button = document.querySelector('button'),
    $pre = document.querySelector('pre'),
    // массив символов для вывода
    safe_list = '1234567890ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'.split(''),
    // т.к. алгоритм будет вырезать из массива значения, скопируем его
    // что бы не изменять исходный массив (просто хорошая практика)
    used_list = safe_list.slice();

$button.addEventListener('click', function(){
  // вырезаем первые пять элементов, и объединяем их в строку с разделителем '<br>'
  $pre.innerHTML = used_list.splice(0, 5).join('<br>');
});
```

```html
<button>Output</button>
<pre></pre>
```